# File upload queue and show loader/progress during upload

Tags: sweetalert2

It's my first time working with sweetalert2, and I'm having a hard time including the "queue" function. I want to show a loading gif or a progress bar while uploading the file in the background, and show the success alert when it's the upload is completed and ready.

Any help is highly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

```
$(function() {

    const uploadReceipt = async function(order_id) {

        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-default',
                input: 'uploadProofButton'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false
        });

        const {value: file} = await swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
            title: 'Confirm Payment',
            text: 'Please upload a payment proof!',
            input: 'file',
            inputAttributes: {
                'name': 'payment_proof',
                'id' : 'payment_proof',
                'accept': 'image/*',
                'aria-label': 'Upload Payment Receipt'
            },
            inputValidator: (value) => {
                if (!value) {
                    return 'You need to choose a payment Proof'
                }
            }
        });

        if(file) {

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('payment_proof', file);
            formData.append('order_id', order_id);

            $.ajax({

                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                url: '/uploadPaymentProof',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {

                    if(response.status == 'success') {

                        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: 'Thank you! Your payment proof has been uploaded successfully'
                        }).then((result) => {
                            $(location).attr("href", '/orders/open')

                        });

                    } else if(response.status == 'error'){

                        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
                            type: 'error',
                            title: 'Error',
                            html: '<div class="text-danger">'+response.errors+'</div>'
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

   $('.ConfirmPayment').click(function() {
       var order_id = $(this).val();
       uploadReceipt(order_id);
   });
});
```